# What is the most efficient way to get all retweets for a list of tweet ids using Twitter API V2

Tags: python, api, twitter, twarc2

I have a list of tweet ids (`tids.csv`) for which I need to collect ALL retweets. Since we can’t directly retrieve retweets of a specific tweet in v2 API, I had to get all retweets of a specific user (users of the tweets in my tid file) and then filter out the retweets of the specific tweets we’re interested in. Here is the command I used to get all retweets of users:

```
while read line; do twarc2 search --archive --start-time "..." --end-time "..." "retweets_of:$line"; done < usernames.txt > usersRetweets.jsonl
```

where usernames.txt is a text file including a list of usernames.

**Note:** I'm using v2 API because v1 API has a limitation of retrieving only 100 most recent retweets, but I need all retweets.

**PROBLEM:**

There are `~17 thousand unique usernames` in my input text file and I found it takes a long time and a very large space to get all retweets of this number of users. For example, it took a couple of days and ~5 GB of space to collect retweets for only ~600 users.

**QUESTION:** What is the most efficient way to get all retweets in terms of time and space?

The above command retrieves all retweets of all tweets for each user, while I only need all retweets of the specific tweets in my dataset (tids.csv).

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION:** Here is what I’m thinking to do:

For each user in username.txt:

1. Retrieve all retweets of a user (setting the start time and end time to the time range I'm interested in)
2. Keep only the retweets that their source tweet id is found in the `tid.csv` file and remove the rest. This can be done by matching the id in `referenced_tweets` field with the ids in tid.csv file)
3. For each remaining retweet, extract only the fields I want in the JSON from the dictionary.
4. Write the dictionary into a file

How can I do it in Python (using twarc2 as a library)?